# How should a client handle receiving data from a separate thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, networking

There are plenty of tutorials on the internet on how to build a server that handles its clients through the creation of separate threads, but there is no tutorials (at least I couldn't find any) on how to build a client that receives data from a separate thread and processes it on the main thread.

I have tried the following approach:

- App class has members `std::vector<JSON> received_messages` and `std::thread network_thread`
- `network_thread` runs an infinite `while` loop, receives data in a blocking manner, parses it when it receives data and it places the JSON object in the `received_messages` vector for the main UI thread to process
- Main UI processes the data inside the vector

While this seemed to be a good idea at first, I realised that I'd have to block the main UI thread as I was processing the data I received. If I were to process the data in a separate process, I would have to deal with a lot of complicated synchronization issues. How should I go around implementing this application?

Comment: You have to understand that whether or not you use threads on the client, that the client in client-server is, in general, an out-of-date view on the server data the moment it leaves the server.  So, you need user experience that accommodates that.  Sometimes that means you cannot order something you put in your shopping cart an hour ago, b/c it is no longer available (or at the same price).  The UI will differ based on the application and its ability to present a meaningful view.  Think stock ticker & trades for an example of constantly changing data where the user wants to take action.

Comment: If you process the received data on the main UI thread, how long would the thread be busy with that? What type of application are you creating? Do you need to render 60 frames per second, or just react to user-input in a responsive manner?

Comment: I am making a chatting application but I would like to learn how to handle it in a game as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long does the processing take?

If the processing is fast, you have no problem.

If the processing is slow, you have a problem when you run it on the main thread, *no matter what you do*. "Slow" processing must either be split up into chunks (each of which are "fast"), or run on a different thread than the main thread.

Since you say you are making a chat application, you probably fall into the first category: processing chat messages is fast, so there is nothing to worry about.